# How to delete offline dictionaries in Google Translate?

Tags: internal-storage, file-management, google-translate

I have downloaded some dictionaries for off-line translation in Google Translate. Those dictionaries are quite big, and take precious internal storage - there is no option to move them to SD.

I'd like to delete those files, as it turns out that I never needed them - always was in range of WiFi. Google Translate doesn't seem to provide an option to do this. I'd rather not remove my configuration (that's what I think would be the result of deleting all user data for Google Translate).

How can I do this?

Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (GT-I8190N), with Android 4.1.2

Comment: They would probably be in `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Offline languages, there you should see the saved dictionaries with a tick inside a grey circle. Tap on the tick and it will ask whether you want to delete the offline package or not, just press OK and it will free up some space.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. Neither tap, nor long press gives an option to delete offline package. v4.4.0.RC01....

Comment: That's weird, at least for the first digits it appears we have the same version of the app